# Trouble with URL rewriting in .htaccess

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^articles/(\d+)*$ ./articles.php?id=$1
```

So, if the URL `foo.com/articles/123` is requested, control is transferred to `articles.php?id=123`.

However, if the requested URL is:

```
foo.com/articles/123/
```

or

```
foo.com/articles/123/whatever
```

I get a "404 Not Found" response.

I would like to call `articles.php?id=123` in all these cases. So, if the URL starts with `foo.com/articles/[digits]...` no matter what other characters follow the digits, I would like to execute `articles.php?id=[digits]`. (The rest of the URL is discarded.)

How do I have to change the regular expression in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't look for the end:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(\d+) ./articles.php?id=$1
```

Comment: FWIW, that's not *PHP* syntax, it's *regular expression* syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to allow the trailing `/` with:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(\d+)/?$
```

The `\d+` will only match decimals. And the `$` would disallow matches beyond the end.

If you also need trailing identifiers, then you need to allow them too. Then it might be best to make the match unspecific:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(.+)$
```

Here `.+` matches virtually anything.

But if you want to keep the numeric id separate then combine those two options:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(\d+)(/.*)?$   ./articles.php?id=$1
```